# How can I read data from socket til nothing is left?

Tags: sockets, haskell

The `recv` function in `Network.Socket` or `Network.Socket.Bytestring` requires an arguments - the length of data to read. In my project I can't know the length of data to read from a socket.

And I want to a) read all data that comes together b) and concatenate it

For instance, in Elixir this does what I want:

```
:gen_tcp.recv(my_socket, 0)
```

In Haskell I think I can do that in a loop, with `fix`. But how presicely to do it with `recv` and assemble and return a whole `ByteString` from a loop too?

Besides, in the documentation it says that if `recv` returns 0 bytes, it means that a socket of the other side got shut down. However, that doesn't imply that all data has been read and that's why it got shut down, does it? If correct, how can I even detect that?

Comment: Hi perhaps this `recv` example might be of interest https://typeclasses.com/phrasebook/monitoring

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, `recv` is a blocking call. It *won't* return until either a non-zero number of bytes are available, or the socket is indeed closed. A non-blocking read would return a value of type `Maybe Bytestring`, for example with `Nothing` indicating no data available at the moment, `Just ""` indicating a closed socket, and `Just x` indicating a successful read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest and better solution might be to convert the socket to a `Handle` and read it as such, as suggested in another answer, but here's one way of doing it using `recv`:

```
import Network.Socket
import Network.Socket.ByteString
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Builder as BB
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import Data.Monoid (mempty,(<>))

readAll :: Socket -> IO BL.ByteString
readAll sock = go (mempty :: BB.Builder)
  where
    go b = do
        bytes <- recv sock 1024 
        if B.length bytes == 0
           then pure $ BB.toLazyByteString b
           else go (b <> BB.byteString bytes)
```

There are 3 main types involved:

- [`B.ByteString`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.10.0/docs/Data-ByteString.html#t:ByteString) Basically an array of bytes in memory.
- [`BB.Builder`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.10.0/docs/Data-ByteString-Builder.html#t:Builder) Can be [created](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.10.0/docs/Data-ByteString-Builder.html#v:byteString) from `B.ByteString`, and it supports *efficient concatenation* with the `Monoid` method [`mappend`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#v:mappend) (which is the same as the `<>` operator). Can be [converted](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.10.0/docs/Data-ByteString-Builder.html#v:toLazyByteString) into `BL.ByteString`.
- [`BL.ByteString`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.10.0/docs/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html#t:ByteString) Internally, a list of `B.ByteString` values. Externally, it has a very similar interface to `B.ByteString`. Can be "compacted" into a single contiguous `B.ByteString` using [`BL.toStrict`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.10.0/docs/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html#v:toStrict).

---

Alternatively, the module [`Network.Socket.ByteString.Lazy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-3.1.1.1/docs/Network-Socket-ByteString-Lazy.html) provides the [`getContents`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-3.1.1.1/docs/Network-Socket-ByteString-Lazy.html#v:getContents) function, but this function uses lazy I/O, which is difficult to understand and prone to cause unpleasant surprises.

Comment: why  builder and lazy bytes? If I use simply strict ByteString and concatenate that, won't it be ok?

Comment: @Rubashka351 Yes, that would work because `B.ByteString` also has a `Monoid` instance. And the code would be simpler. But the concatenation would be expensive, because each `<>` operation for `B.ByteString` allocates a new array in memory for the result, and copies the contents of the two argument arrays. The `Builder` type is designed to avoid that. One might also ask: why does `Builder` "return" a `BL.ByteString` and not the strict version? For many uses, `BL.ByteString` works just fine, and using it lets us avoid the final "compaction" `BL.toStrict` step.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to buffer up all of a socket's contents at once, you don't really need any fancy socket-handling code. Just [convert your Socket to a Handle](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-3.1.1.1/docs/Network-Socket.html#v:socketToHandle), and use `hGetContents` to read the whole thing.

Comment: Perhaps it would be a good idea to specify the exact version of `hGetContents`. There are several across the "base" and "bytestring" packages. Some use lazy I/O, others read the handle strictly.